# Can I reveal a HTML element in Chrome with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools

If you in Chrome workspace javascript Console do

```
document.querySelector("#some-id")
```

the element with this id will be shown in the console. You can then right-click on it to reveal it in the Elements tab. Can I reveal it in the Elements tab with javascript instead?

Comment: document.querySelector("#some-id").innerHTML?

Comment: You can show it if it is 'hidden with something like `document.querySelector("#some-id").style.display = "block"`

Comment: that's not what this question is asking.

Comment: Thanks, @KevinB, you are right. I want to avoid the right-clicking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the `inspect` method.

```
inspect(document.querySelector("#some-id"));
```

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#inspecting_dom_elements_and_javascript_heap_objects